# APP rejected by reason 2.16

Tags: ios

From Apple
2.16 - Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc

detail
Your app uses the Location Background mode but does not include the required "battery use" disclaimer in your Application Description

last time my app is ok to submit，what should i do ？change the info.plist？

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to add it in your plist but you need to wirte **"The continued use of GPS may decrease battery life"** (like this) in your application meta data description in itunes connect app.